# Is there a coding library that exists to determine prepositions of place for a given word?

Tags: grammaire, informatique, ressources

I'm writing a program that will do some language processing in French, spitting out sentences composed from various data points. For example, "*Jean t'a appelé hier à 15h12*", because in the database there is a record for an inbound phone call yesterday at 3:12PM from one of your contacts, Jean, just to give you an idea of what I mean.

So I'm looking for a library (in Python preferably) that has already implemented the logic of, for a given location, whether one should say "à" ou "en", etc. For example:

*"Tu as été **à Paris** l'année dernière"*

*"Tu as été **en Angleterre** cette année"*

Does such a library/API exist? *Merci beaucoup !*

Comment: It probably exists inside some complex natural language processing models, but a library/API...

Comment: I've had good luck with various NLP packages in python.

Comment: @Frank any examples?

Comment: @daveslab https://www.nltk.org/, but not specifically for this problem when I used it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the [Language tool](https://languagetool.org/fr/) API which seems to be remarkably good at correcting preposition usage errors:

[image: example of languagetool correction]

Unfortunately, with great power comes great price. The API isn't free.

Otherwise, if you have access to the location category of your sentence (city or country, for example) you can implement the grammar rules and known exceptions yourself, even if it's a bit tedious.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, unfortunately the library would need offline access. You're right that I could implement the rules myself, but indeed it would be quite tedious.